# 2 Column website layout with full background slideshow or video

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm doing a website that needs to have layout such as the one here:

http://newsmartwave.net/wordpress/trego/home/homepage-1/#featured_products

I've spent 2 days researching how to do proper 2 column layout and tried different options, but none seem to work just right.

Right now I have 2 versions - http://aspenwebsites.com/mpwebsite/index.html  and http://aspenwebsites.com/mpwebsite/index_alt.html

The problem with the first one is that if you reduce the height of the browser's window considerably I end up with some white space bellow the sidebar and some of my text ends up outside the border (see screenshot).

The problem with eh second one is that I don't can't place a full-screen background image behind both columns.

In addition, unlike on the sample website ( http://aspenwebsites.com/mpwebsite/index.html  and http://aspenwebsites.com/mpwebsite/index_alt.html) that I'm trying to duplicate, I'd like to have a vertical scroll bar appear if browser's window reaches certain minimum height.

I know people sometimes get annoyed with types of questions, but I really just can't figure this out and I did read numerous articles and examples.

I'm not asking to write code for me, although any code samples would be most appreciated. Minimally, I was hoping for directions for some good tutorial, as I really would like to master this layout. It comes up a lot in my work and I'd like to have my own code that I have 100% understanding of rather than using Wordpress.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st one, add `overflow: scroll;` to the `#sidebar > .row` rule.

You **do have** a fullscreen background image in the second one. It's just that #maincontent, which is in front of it, has a `background:white;` rule, so you can't see it.

Edit: I did not get annoyed by the way..

Comment: gee... my wires must have really crossed in the last couple of days from all the looking at different code and examples. :)  Thank you for pointing that out!!